# Optimization of Linux (Ubuntu) for RDP

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, optimization

I am building up a pool of virtual machines for remote access via RDP. Currently, I want to stay on Linux side and avoid the need for using any Windows machines. Therefore I tested the latest most common derivates with the same hardware resources (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Mint, Debian). I installed the xrdp package on them and connected myself via the RDP-client of Microsoft (atm the connecting clients have Windows 7 installed).

While testing I noticed that the performance (mostly the fluent interaction with the UI) differs depending on the Linux derivate. To sum it up, for me Ubuntu did the best job. (Nevertheless, without [creating a policy exception and fixing theme issues](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12198), the RDP session on Ubuntu 18.04 did not work 100% perfect (e.g. misses dock)).

Now my question is: are there any optimization steps to tweak the performance? E.g. when one is connecting to a Windows machine it usually does things like only displaying the edges of a dragged window (which is not done by Linux).

It would be nice to see if somebody decided to use Linux for this job and additionally realized optimizations regarding the RDP-session.